# How can I use another column's data for creating sessions by just username and password query from db

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to create login operation.

How can I use another column's data by using a username and password query to my db.

In my db, there is a another column(`personnel_type_id`) and I want to create a session with username and password but also the personnel_type_id data.

How can I use `personel_type_id` data without using another parameter in my code?

```
protected void btnGiris_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       string sorgu = "Select * from Personnels where VS_personnel_username = @kullaniciAdi AND VS_personnel_password= @sifre ";

       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sorgu, cnn);
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kullaniciAdi", txtKullaniciAdi.Text);
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sifre", txtSifre.Text);

       cnn.Open();

       SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

       if (dr.Read())
       {
           Session.Timeout = 300;
           Session.Add("kullaniciAdi", dr["VS_personnel_username"].ToString());
           Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
       }
       else
       {
           lblSonuc.Text = "Kullanıcı girişi sağlanamadı";

       }
       cnn.Close();
}
```

Comment: I dont get what you are asking please give more explanation

Comment: @kaushik-maheta ı want to create users page according user's type,but how can ı pull that column without using text button on page.they just use username and password,then ı going to directing them according theirs type in my db. ?

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like:

```
protected void btnGiris_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       string sorgu = "Select * from Personnels where VS_personnel_username = @kullaniciAdi AND VS_personnel_password= @sifre ";

       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sorgu, cnn);
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kullaniciAdi", txtKullaniciAdi.Text);
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sifre", txtSifre.Text);

       cnn.Open();

       SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

       if (dr.Read())
       {
           Session.Timeout = 300;
           Session.Add("kullaniciAdi", dr["VS_personnel_username"].ToString());
           Session.Add("your_user_id_parameter", dr["personnel_type_id"].ToString());
           Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
       }
       else
       {
           lblSonuc.Text = "Kullanıcı girişi sağlanamadı";

       }
       cnn.Close();
}
```

If you don't want/can/need to store that "personnel_type_id" as a session variable you have to implement some kind of lookup in the database each time you need it.